# Windows Phone ListPicker ItemsSource List<int> Binding

Tags: binding, windows-phone, datatemplate, listpicker

I am using a `ListPicker` to let the user choose from a list of numbers, so I bind the `ItemsSource` property to my `List<int>` property in my `ViewModel`. It works fine and it displays my nubmers, but only with the default `FullIModeltemTemplate`. If I create a new one and add a `TextBlock`, I am not able to bind its `Text` property to my numbers.

What do I need to do to bind my numbers in the new  `FullModelItemTemplate`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out the way to bind it:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="RadiusLFullItemTemplate">
        <Grid d:DesignWidth="446" d:DesignHeight="79">
            <TextBlock Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path = .}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="48"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Text = {Binding Path =.}" did the trick